# How to create a table and its related model.py automatically from a csv file in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, csv, django-admin

Think of this:

You create a CMS of some sort, which asks you for an application name and a **csv** file for that application.
Then it automatically creates that app on the fly, creates the required **model.py** based on the csv columns, activates the admin page for it and allows only you to have the full permission to this new table via django admin, then it inserts the the app into the url.py and creates the view.py for it as well.

Then all you'd have to do is upload a csv, name your app and whola!, you have an admin page to play with.

Now, is there anyway to create an app or at least a model.py out of a csv file in django or is there any django-app that can do this?

Note: Look beyond (./manage.py inspectdb > models.py)

Comment: Are you planning to specify the types of each of the columns in the csv file? Editing model.py seems pretty easy to me already, too, but it's an interesting idea...

Comment: Yes, once the the csv has been loaded up, each column will get auto detected (best case) and a drop down menu will have show up where you can set each field to whatever type you want before pressing "go". Only then it will create model.py, syncdb, url and view and setting changes.

Comment: I assume the goal is to make app creation easier.  You can write a tool that does code-generation given a specific format.  However, odds are you'll spend more time on your code-generation tool.  Give it a try, and see how it goes.  If the django coding overhead is bothering you, you might want to try a lighter framework.

Comment: Hi monkut, django coding overhead is just fine, no bother here. Think of it as creating an application on the fly based on a single csv file. I need to create on foo.com, "A" which is based on simply uploading "A.csv" and have it deployed automatically at: foo.com/A,. Same goes with B (foo.com/B). Note that, foo.com/(A|B|*) will have common templates which is a search bar that is specific for their each models. thx.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not involve creating an actual models.py and application, you may want to look into [dynamically creating Model classes at runtime](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels). You could have "meta" models that store the information on the dynamic models, and then have your CSV view import the data into those models, create the classes, and register them with the admin. Or something like that.

Creating an actual application directory, with models.py, views.py, and so on, is fairly easy (just create the directory, create the files, and write formatted strings to them based on the CSV data). Editing the *project's* settings.py and urls.py, and reloading the modules, wouldn't be too difficult either. But, I wouldn't trust automatically generated Django applications without first looking at them.